# Insert and Delete row from TableView using Core Data and Array

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a single tableView with multiple sections.  These sections are populated from an 'items' array, which actually combines two different fetch requests into a single array of dictionaries.  The first fetch request pulls 'uncollected' items and the second one 'collected' items.

The table view populates fine, and I can add/remove items fairly easily.  I can also select the accessory for an uncollected cell and it will move to the 'collected' section.  I am doing all of this using reloadData after any change to data, and am now attempting to convert this into animated inserts/deletes.  I am starting with the transition from 'uncollected' to 'collected', which should result in a cell deletion from the former section and insertion in the latter section.

I am a little confused about the order of things.  As I understand it I should:

1. update the item (it switches from collected == NO to YES)
2. save my managed object context
3. the 'items' array that drives the table is now updated automaticall
4. insert/delete rows

I am finding that I get the error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.
```

The tableView is in a TableViewController, which is the table view's delegate.  I've implemented numberOfSections, numberOfRows etc correctly I think.  In these I return the counts from my 'items' array.

My code is below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    Item *item = [self itemForIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;  

    if (![item collected]) {
        //update item
        [item setCollected:YES];
        [item setDateCollected:[NSDate date]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![item.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving collected/uncollected items");
        }

        //update cell
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //update tableview
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:self.items.count]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[tableView endUpdates];
    }
    else if ([item collected]){...do the opposite
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:self.items.count]
```

with

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.items.count inSection:0]
```

?

Comment: No, I'm trying to insert the item in the top row of the last section (which is always my collected items)